# Is having a primary key on each table mean that my table/database is "properly" indexed (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

In MySQL, does having a primary key on each table mean that my table/database is "properly" indexed?

If not, do I just need to put indices on commonly `join`ed fields and/or fields which are commonly targeted with `where` clauses?

I always hear I need to "properly" index my database and understand a main point of indexing is to limit the searching the query needs to do. However, I have never really understood what people mean when they say "properly". In reading other SO Q&A I realize the answer(s) may not be simple but any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Indexes are used to improve performance.  You need to create indexes wherever it will be faster for MySQL to find a particular row by using them than simply to scan the entire database, and the time saved is significant to you.  Indexes come at a cost: space + extra time on inserts and updates.  So you also need to consider if the time saving benefit is large enough to justify the cost.

Comment: "properly" means what is best for your situation.  Indexing fields that are commonly used in where clauses is a good idea.

Comment: @DanBracuk does having a primary key mean my table is indexed?

Comment: It means it has one such index -- and yes, typically JOINs are based on the primary key from one table being included in another table; but there's no guarantee that's sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a primary key doesn't necessarily mean that your tables are properly indexed (unless you only have very simple queries).

Design the indexes based on the queries your application runs against the tables.

See my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: thanks for you very nice presentation, i tried implementing pt-query-digest but had immediate issue even though "mysql-slow.log" exists in said location and has `777` permissions: `$ /usr/local/bin/pt-query-digest \ /Applications/MNPP/tmp/mysql/mysql-slow.log \ > ~/pqd.txt` **error:** `/Applications/MNPP/tmp/mysql/mysql-slow.log does not exist or is not readable at /usr/local/bin/pt-query-digest line 11435.
  does not exist or is not readable at /usr/local/bin/pt-query-digest line 11435.`

Comment: You can also read stdin, for example `cat /Applications/MNPP/tmp/mysql/mysql-slow.log | pt-query-digest ...` If that doesn't work, I'd double-check the permissions on the log file and also the directory it lives in.  You could also run `sudo pt-query-digest ...` to bypass permissions.

Comment: Ok `cat` as shown below is [at least giving me some output](http://d.pr/i/IUm5) in the pqd.txt file. However, its not listing each query as I perform it as in your slides. `root# cat /Applications/MNPP/tmp/mysql/mysql-slow.log | /Users/TimPeterson/percona-toolkit-2.1.9/bin/pt-query-digest > ~/pqd.txt`

Comment: The log includes only queries that take more than [long_query_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) seconds to execute.  The default long_query_time is 10 seconds.  Read more about the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: ah ok thanks, i tried to `SET GLOBAL long_query_time=0` but it wouldn't let me change it and stayed as 10 seconds. I assume their is some permissions somewhere? On the other hand I was able to change `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=ON` so don't know why the difference.

Comment: You need to be running MySQL 5.1 or later to change long_query_time to 0.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have long-running database sessions if you use persistent connections or connection pools.  Sessions only read global variables at the start of the session, i.e. changing a global variable doesn't affect a session already running.  I'm getting warnings about this comment thread going on too long -- I suggest you take further pt-query-digest questions to https://groups.google.com/group/percona-discussion